# Using mstate in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am using the `mstate` program to estimate an illness-death model and have a few questions that I'm hoping a more seasoned mstate user might have insights into.

My first question is quite basic:

Is it an issue if the start time is not always greater than the stop time? For example, below is a selection of cases in the data for whom Tstart>=Tstop:

```
       ID   Tstart    Tstop trans status
480   228 5.111874 5.111874     3      0
587   277 4.996568 4.996568     3      0
1184  567 5.015786 5.015786     3      0
1258  603 0.000000 0.000000     1      1
1259  603 0.000000 0.000000     2      0
1397  667 0.000000 0.000000     1      1
1398  667 0.000000 0.000000     2      0
```

As you can see, the issue is actually that my Tstart=Tstop.

I set up my model like this:
`model <- coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, status) ~  x.1 + x.2 + x.3 .... + strata(strata), data = example, method = "breslow")` , and after running my model (which does run and provide estimates), this is the error message I recieve:

```
Stop time must be > start time, NA created
```

My second question is a bit more complex. Namely, is there a way to include a time-updated variable that is not a new state? For example, if I am interested in the risk of disease X, but have an exposure of interest that can change between time of study entry and diagnosis of disease X.

Comment: 1st question: It's not an error (only a warning) and it seems fairly informative (telling you that those cases were ignored.) Second question. So sorry. SO doesn't do 2nd questions. Post a new question with full details, and I'n guessing you really should read the highly upvoted question:  "How to make a great reproducible question in R".

Comment: Thank you for the input and feedback. I knew that it is a warning message, but I just wanted to make sure that, statistically speaking, this does not cause an issue with the validity of my analysis.